# How can I answer inline queries in telegram bots in php(laravel) with Telebot plugin?

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

How can I answer inline queries in telegram bots in php(laravel) with Telebot plugin? I'm working on a bot project in laravel and I'm using the Telebot package.

does Telebot support answerInlineQuery method? I can't find it.

> ```
>     \WeStacks\TeleBot\Laravel\TeleBot::answerInlineQuery([]); //this doesn't exist.
> ```

how should I answer Inline Queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is:

```
Methods/AnswerInlineQueryMethod.php
```

[File in package](https://github.com/westacks/telebot/blob/master/src/Methods/AnswerInlineQueryMethod.php)

Comment: Oh! I think there was a problem with phpstorm because it showed auto-correct for all methods except this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is supported. However, just seen the [facade](https://github.com/westacks/telebot/blob/master/src/Laravel/TeleBot.php) missing it in PHPDoc. Please create an issue on a GitHub, or create a pull request, so I don't forget to fix it. Thanks for using my library.

Comment: created a pull request, adding it to the phpDoc. thanks for the great library.